# Azure AD B2C - Retrieve account lockout time

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

After N failed login attempts with a wrong password the account get's locked.

Documentation says the lockout interval increases after further failed login attempts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-password-smart-lockout#manage-azure-ad-smart-lockout-values

Is there a way to query this information, how long the account is still locked? With Graph API for instance. 
I would like to show this information to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subsequent lockouts duration times are not published. Its also not recommended to create customized error messages providing a possible attacker the lockout period. However, please free to provide your @ https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory.

Comment: Is this officially documented somewhere?